# Sharing and Reputation badges on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, badges, sharing

I have observed that Stack Overflow gives badges for sharing questions over social media websites.

I have few doubts about it.

1. How is the number to which the question is shared counted? Say I have 1000 followers on Facebook, and if I share it on Facebook wall, does it count to 1000 shares, or only if someone clicks on link shared by me and views, only that count is considered?
2. If I shared a question, got a badge and later remove that shared post, will the badge would be removed or nullified?
3. Will Stack Overflow have more sharing options other than Facebook, twitter and g+?
4. If I share a question in my blog, will that be counted too?

Comment: To answer one of your questions (except in exception circumstances like voting fraud) badges are never removed

Comment: I know about [badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (Announcer, Booster, Publicist), but this is the first time I read about getting reputation points for sharing a question.

Comment: @Martin there is still no reputation from sharing...not sure where that idea came from

Comment: @Martin and Nick, I will edit my question to that respect. Thank you.

Comment: @Martin well, usually sharing means more views and more views means higher chance to get upvotes, considering it's a good post. Hence one can say sharing gives reputation, to the post author. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not just the author, but any good answerers can benefit too. :)

Comment: @AnonJr yup good point. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How is the number to which the question is shared counted, say I have 1000 followers on facebook, and if I share it on facebook wall, does it count to 1000 shares, or only if someone clicks on link shared by me and views, only that count is considered?

We have no way to know who looked at a link on another site. By sharing we mean - someone used the link and came to the site.

> If I shared a question, got reputation or badge and later remove that shared post, will the reputation or badge would be removed or nullified?

If the reputation change is older than 60 days, it will remain even if the post is deleted. Badges are not revoked.

> Will stackoverflow have more sharing options other than facebook, twitter and g+?

If they make sense.

> If I share a question in my blog, will that be counted too?

Yes.

Comment: When you click the "share" link you get something like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191375/152859` - the last number is your own (the user who clicked share) user ID so this way by checking the referrer, the code knows who shared the link.